# How can I set a single .bashrc file for several users?

Tags: bash

during my work I need to constantly add alias commands to bashrc, most of those commands needs to be runed by other users. is there any way I could add alias commands to a bashrc from external source?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Many config files in users home directory just override/add to ones in the `/etc` - for example the settings for GIMP in the users home are in `~/.gimp-2.*`, which adds to the system-wide config `/etc/gimp/2.0`.

So for `~/.bashrc`, you could edit the system wide config files `/etc/bash.bashrc` *(for functions/aliases*) or `/etc/profile` *(for environment stuff)* - you can the full list from `man bash`:

```
FILES
       /bin/bash
              The bash executable
       /etc/profile
              The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
       /etc/bash.bash_logout
              The systemwide login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
       ~/.bash_profile
              The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
       ~/.bashrc
              The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
       ~/.bash_logout
              The individual login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
       ~/.inputrc
              Individual readline initialization file
```

This warning is given for a few Linux systems in the files:

```
# It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates.
```

So you could edit those files, you may want to back them up first (`cp /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc-backup` for example), or [create a shell script in `/etc/profile.d`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170201104140/http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/08/setup-a-universal-user-profile-with-etcprofile-dcustom-sh/) - for example you can create one with these commands (with sudo/as root):

```
touch /etc/profile.d/custom.sh
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/custom.sh
```

Then open it with `nano /etc/profile.d/custom.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
alias ls='ls -lah'
```

And check whether it works by seeing if it appears in the output of `alias` - Note that you may need to logout/login or reboot to see any changes (if you don't want to, running `source /etc/profile` after any changes might work)

Comment: Plenty of good suggestions there. I think there is one other option, which would be worth mentioning as well. One can edit `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to change what the contents of `~/.bashrc` will look like for newly created users.

Comment: @kasperd - nice idea (you could do a answer on it if you want)

Comment: In my experience, `~/.bash_logout` and `/etc/bash.bash_logout` do not work. :(

Comment: AFAIK alias in `/etc/profile.d/` will *not* be picked up by sub-process right? So the alias is only available when Bash is the log-in shell?

Comment: I think some of them only work when its used in say a TTY as the only environment, in a desktop terminal some of them may not be used. I'd have to test this to verify this though and can't at the moment!

Answer (score 10):

Go to `/etc/bash.bashrc`

> vim /etc/bash.bashrc

and make your alias there.

add your alias in last line.

> alias abc="whatever"

That alias will become global for all users.

but for security reasons we dont recommend you that.

there is `profile.d` directory which contains user-environment files

go to

> cd /etc/profile.d/
>
> vim aliases

and add your aliases here.

without effecting your system files. It is safe and right way to work with your environment files.

Answer (score 3):

There's already an accepted answer here, but you might consider using some form of environment modules to handle system-wide configuration of user environments rather than messing with the files in /etc/profile.d, etc. This is especially true if you want to manage this control in one place across lots of shells. [Lmod](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lmod/) (under very active development), [C/TCL modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) (the classic solution), or [Cmod](http://www.lysator.liu.se/cmod/) (lightweight).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I'm doing it right, but it works for me to keep a /home/ComunAtodos directory (capitalized and in spanish to make evident that it is not a linux native directory) and put .bashrc, .nanorc and .bash_aliases there. 
Then I reference those in /etc/skel/.profile so new users point to them, and only add extras to specific users that need them.

Answer (score -1):

I'm really new to Linux operativ system, but i did a sketch of a bash script that works to modify all the users .bashrc file and not the system file /etc/.bashrc file.

```
#!/bin/bash

X=$( cat etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d: ) #All-users

For X in /home/*/.bashrc ; do 

echo "alias ls='ls -al'" >> $X

2>/dev/null

done

source $X

exit 0
```

Okay so i know that that script works, but i don't if it's fault free :) 
Also u can modify it so it doesn't involves all the users, maybe u make a file for all the users that need their .bashrc file customized.

Comment: First line (where you read /etc/passwd) seems to do nothing.  Your 4th line seems to be a mistake (and I don't see why you'd want to suppress errors).  "exit 0" is redundant.  This requires all users to already have a `.bashrc` file, and always appends regardless of whether the line is already in their file.

Comment: I was thinking to get the names of all users with that line? But now that i think about it i could just do cut < /etc/passwd, there was alot of names on that list so i didn't want IT to make errrors for those who doesn't have bashrc filé. How can u append only if the line doesn't exist ? And could u Write the proper script for this type of rask please i have only been using Linux for a week.

Comment: Looks like you already have some skills but this tutorial is a good one for shell scripting: https://www.shellscript.sh/ .
For other questions such as how to append a line only if it doesn't already exist, feel free to ask them as new questions on here.