# No path in .bashrc

Tags: 14.04, paths

I am trying to add path in .bashrc ( sudo gedit ~/.bashrc). When I search for exiting path there is none.
But if I echo $PATH on terminal prompt I do see some paths.
I need to edit (add to) the PATH for the newly installed application
How do I do, ~/.profile also unable to edit

Thanks

Comment: Or, possible duplicate of How can I set a single .bashrc file for several users? : http://askubuntu.com/q/503216/566421

Answer (score 2):

First, do you mean "existing `PATH`"? Second don't use `sudo` to edit files in your `$HOME` directory. (`sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) ~/.bashrc` to ensure it's editable by you).

Your `PATH` is set up by other startup files (see `man bash`, the `INVOCATION` section).

You can add a directory to your `PATH` in your `~/.bashrc` thusly:

```
export savedPATH="$PATH"
export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"
```

You can, in a terminal, type `PATH=${savedPATH}"` if you mess up `PATH` (can't find commands).

Comment: .bashrc is editable by me (using sudo) but unable to figure out what to do or should I edit .bashrc or some other file as I do not find any existing PATH in .bashrc